unable to generate Paypal Referal Link
I am working on paypal onboarding seller to my platform.
I am following this paypal referral
but i got this error
{
"msg": "{"name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","debug_id":"f88411690d4c9","message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.","details":[{"issue":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","description":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions."}]}"
}
can someone please elaborate which permission is required and how can i get those permissions
i am using this code
 @staticmethod
def create_paypal_referral(email, tracking_id, return_url):
    """Create a PayPal partner referral."""
    success = False
    response = None

    try:
        # Get access token
        access_token = PaypalrestSDk.get_access_token()
        print(access_token)
        # Define headers and payload for the referral request
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        }

        data = json.dumps({
            "email": email,
            "tracking_id": tracking_id,
            "partner_config_override": {
                "return_url": return_url,
                "return_url_description": "The URL to return the merchant after the PayPal onboarding process.",
                "show_add_credit_card": True
            },
            "operations": [
                {
                    "operation": "API_INTEGRATION",
                    "api_integration_preference": {
                        "rest_api_integration": {
                            "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
                            "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY",
                            "third_party_details": {
                                "features": ["PAYMENT", "REFUND", "PARTNER_FEE"]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "products": ["PAYMENT_METHODS"],
            "capabilities": ["APPLE_PAY"],
            "legal_consents": [
                {
                    "type": "SHARE_DATA_CONSENT",
                    "granted": True
                }
            ]
        })

        # Make the request to PayPal's partner referrals API
        referral_url = f'{settings.PAYPAL_BASE_URL}/v2/customer/partner-referrals'
        response = requests.post(referral_url, headers=headers, data=data)
        
        if response.status_code == 201:
            success = True
            response = response.json()
        else:
            response = response.text

        return success, response
    except Exception as e:
        response = str(e)
        return success, response

@staticmethod
def get_access_token():
    """Retrieve an access token using PayPal OAuth2 API."""
    oauth_url = f'{settings.PAYPAL_BASE_URL}/v1/oauth2/token'

    response = requests.post(
        oauth_url,
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json', 'Accept-Language': 'en_US'},
        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET),
        data={'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
    )
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json().get('access_token')


How are you calling it, with what credentials? Please share your code and obfuscate your credentials.

i have share the code i using. i want you notify that i am using sandbox account and url for in this case

It's unclear how this works, you should probably provide something people here can reproduce, but from what you've shared, the obvious issue would be that the token you obtain through PaypalrestSDk.get_access_token() simply doesn't get you sufficient permission to make this request.


For sandbox, create a Platform app via https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications
For live, contact PayPal to become an approved partner. If approved you'll be provisioned with a platform app.


This generate url but on clicking url i got {"name":"AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE","message":"Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error","rel":"information_link"}]}
